# solve the infinite chord problem with the Fourier transform

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-transform

I was trying solve infinite rope,I need to solve this problem with a different method than the traditional one, (homogeneous case, with D'alambert). Using Fourier transform I think it could be easier but I have not been able to achieve it, can you help me?

$$u_{tt}-c^2u_{xx}=0, -\infty<x<\infty, t>0 $$
$u(x,0)=f(x), u_{t}(x,0)=g(x), \infty<x<\infty$

Comment: Which variable did you take the Fourier Transform over? $x$ or $t$?